# Proper way to use Canonical and/or prev/next links

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have a website, **example.com**, which pulls information from a database, pagination is used so that there are only 12 items displayed per page.

I allow users to view the information (ORDER BY) as they like:

- example.com/new/1 (year DESC)
- example.com/old/1 (year ASC)
- example.com/alpha/1 (title ASC)
- example.com/recent/1 (id DESC)

Basically, example.com?sort=new&page=1

Problem #1:

**example.com** is exactly the same as **example.com/recent/1**, I use a switch statement to check if any sorting feature is selected, if not "recent" (id DESC) is selected.

If users visit **example.com**, should they be redirected to **example.com/recent/1**?

Problem #2:

I'm confused on how I should set the Canonical link in regards to the sorting (ordering?) method(s), can I just put example.com, or must I make individual Canonical links?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/new/1" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/old/1" />
```

Not sure how to handle my main page, considering it's the same as /recent/1.

Thanks!

Edit: I'm not attempting to separate an article into sections, but let's say displaying several articles through pagination.

Comment: Have you looked at the recommendations from Google? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en or any of the other articles about the subject? https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-and-seo-best-practices-common-issues/

Comment: Indeed. I tested making unique canons for each order, and setting prev/next links; however, I realized that I may have to create new content for each order (title, site introduction) to avoid duplicate content. This is where I became worried about setting a Canon for my index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got three options:

- basic url pagination cannonicalized to a "default" url.
- cannonicalize everything to a bot-targeted un-paginated list.
- combine both options, plus implement lazy-loading pagination.

## Cannonicalize to your "default" paginated url

Whether you decide to allow pagination on your base-url `example.com/2` or on a specific path `example.com/recent/3`, everything should be cannonicalized (with prev/next) to that url.

If I assume that alternate pages can only be reached via `/recent/#`, then you should simply cannonicalize ALL sorting and paged urls to `/recent/`. Then set the prev/next cannonicalization to the ordered url.

#### /recent/4

- can: /recent
- prev: /recent/3
- next: /recent/5

#### /recent/1

- can: /recent
- next: /recent/2

#### /old/7

- can: /recent
- prev: /old/6
- next: /old/8

The primary reasoning for this comes from the purpose, and effect, of prev/next canonicalization.  In particular, it tells a search index to treat all pages as a single large page. The result is that the content between ordering urls is identical as far as google is concerned.

## Be smarter than simple prev/next, and follow google's advice

An alternate approach would be to simply show a giant (unpaginated) response to bots, on your domain root `example.com`, and cannonicalize every page to that, with prev/next specific to the ordered urls.

## Lazy Loading

AFTER you've picked some combination of the above options, it will be time to take a close look at lazy-loading your results, and getting rid of page-numbers in your urls.

This involves using ajax to load and unload, pages and items, outside of view. **EX:** Your user scrolls to page 7, while ajax loads onto the page the items for page 8 and 9, and deletes from the page items for page 3 and 4.

If you do this, google won't care that you're creating bot-targeted content. In fact, they suggest it for some cases of AdSense seo.

## More Reading

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html

Comment: Makes sense. If I set the canonical to /recent, is it ok if my domain still loads in the address bar like "example.com", or should I force it to include the "/recent" via htacces? Would it have an effect on the way my domain is shared (backlinks without the "/recent")?

Comment: No need to force a particular url for viewing content, that's the whole point of cannonicalization. Just set the SAME cannonicalization on your domain root "example.com" You'll probably get a little bit better results if you make the domain root your "default."